# success : function ajax chamar funçao de outro javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, funções, mvc, controller

```
function paginacao_tabela_clientes_status(idpessoa){
  $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: BASE_URL + '/clients/tabela_clientes_pedido_entregue',
            data: {idpessoa: idpessoa},
            success: function (msg)
            {
                var aoColumns = [{"data": "nomedesc"},
                    {"data": "id_pedido"},
                    {"data": "ped_representante"},
                    {"data": "num_sofa"},
                    {"data": "qtde"},
                    {"data": "totalpedido", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2, 'R$ ')}];
                datatable('#table_pedido_entregue', msg, aoColumns);
            }});
```

funçao do clientsController.php da url ajax

```
    public function tabela_clientes_pedido_entregue() {
    $idpessoa = addslashes($_POST['idpessoa']);
    $cli = new Clients;
    $cli->tabela_clientes_pedido_entregue($idpessoa);
}
```

funcao do model Clients.php

```
 function tabela_clientes_pedido_entregue($idpessoa) {
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT 
    `pedido`.`id` AS `id_pedido`,
    pedido.ped_representante,
    itempedido.num_sofa as num_sofa,
    itempedido.nomedesc as nomedesc,
    concat(itempedido.qtde_entregue,'/', itempedido.qtde_solicitada)as qtde,
     SUM(itempedido.qtde_entregue * `itempedido`.`vlr_unitario`)  AS `totalpedido`      
    FROM `pedido`
    JOIN `pessoa` ON (`pedido`.`idcliente` = `pessoa`.`id`)
JOIN `itempedido` ON (pedido.id = `itempedido`.`idpedido`)
    WHERE ((itempedido.qtde_solicitada - itempedido.qtde_entregue)= 0
    or (itempedido.qtde_solicitada - itempedido.qtde_entregue)< itempedido.qtde_solicitada )
    and pedido.idcliente = :idpessoa
    group by pedido.id, pedido.ped_representante,itempedido.num_sofa");
    $sql->bindValue(":idpessoa", $idpessoa);
    $sql->execute();
    $json = array();
    while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

aqui e funcao em javascript que esta no chama_data_tables.js da erro quando e chamada

```
function datatable(tabela, json, data) {
$(tabela).dataTable(
        {
            "aaData": json,
            "aoColumns": data,
            "language": {
                "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ".",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_  Resultados por Página",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sNext": "Próximo",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                    "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                    "sLast": "Último"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                }
            }
        }
);};
```

no servidor local ele reconhece normal coloquei os link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/js/chama_dataTables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/js/paginacao_tabela_clientes_status.js"></script>
```

na home, mas no servidor web ele reconhece o arquivo paginacao_tabela_clientes_status.js normal  ai chamo a funçao 
    datatable('#table_pedido_entregue', msg, aoColumns);
mas o servidor nao reconhece,  aparece no erro

> **Fatal error**:  Class 'assetsController' not found in **/home/marciavarais/public_html/core/core
>   .php** on line **39**
>   o servidor le como se fosse view

essa e view status ela abre da view clients em _blank

```
<h1><center>Status</center></h1>
<h2>Cliente: <?php echo $client_info[0]['id'] ?> - <?php echo     $client_info[0]['nomedesc'] ?> </h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
var BASE_URL = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>";
window.onload = function () {
paginacao_tabela_clientes_status(<?php echo $client_info[0]['id']; ?>);
};
</script>
<div class="tabarea">
<div id="id_form_0" class="tabitemdespesa activetab">Pedidos</div>
<div id="id_form_1" class="tabitemdespesa ">Carga</div>
<div id="id_form_2" class="tabitemdespesa">Conta a Receber ( em  Desenvolvimento)</div>
</div>
<div class="tabcontent">
<div class="tabbody" style="display:block">
    <h3><center>Pedidos entregue</center></h3>
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"   id="table_pedido_entregue"  class="display">
        <thead>  
            <tr>
                <th width="40%" class="select-filter">Descrição  Produto</th>
                <th width="10%"class="select-filter">Nº pedido</th>
                <th width="10%"class="select-filter">Nº ped. repres.</th>
                <th width="10%" class="select-filter">Num_Sofa</th>
                <th width="10%"class="select-filter">Quantidade</th>
                <th width="30%"class="select-filter">Valor Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <link href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/css/cliente_status.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/js/chama_dataTables.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/js/paginacao_tabela_clientes_status.js"></script>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /baseflex/index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Este domínio herda o pacote “PHP”.
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

logs_erros_php

```
[01-Oct-2017 01:35:46 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'assetsController' not found in /home/marciavarais/public_html/core/core.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 /home/marciavarais/public_html/index.php(44): core->run()
#1 {main}
thrown in /home/marciavarais/public_html/core/core.php on line 39
```

depende de qual codigo so tem php na view na requisiçao ajax vo colocar la en cima 
alguem sabe oque pode ser?

Comment: Isso parece mais erro no PHP do que no JavaScript. Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código do PHP? O que seria esse `assetsController`?

Comment: nao existe assetsController,  o servidor ta lendo o link do javascript como se tivesse na url navegador, e o codigo php

Comment: Entendi. Então seu arquivo `.htaccess` deve estar errado, não servindo diretamente os arquivos estáticos. Pode colocar o código dele na pergunta? E está utilizando algum framework ou a aplicação foi desenvolvida do zero?

Comment: foi do zero, framework o problema e manutençao, eu terminei a faculdade e sempre usei c# pra desktop, to começando com web, mas gosto de cria as estrutura do meio jeito rende mais, vo pega codigo e ja posto

Comment: O diretório `assets` existe na raiz do projeto?

Comment: existe, estrutura, asses/js/os scripts, so da erro no servidor web deve se htaccess mesmo, vc viu ali

Comment: Ao meu ver, a aplicação não está conseguindo identificar corretamente algum arquivo estático, que possivelmente não existe, e analisando a requisição com o PHP. Como o PHP espera que o primeiro valor da URL seja o controlador, ele tenta executar o `assetsController`, gerando o erro apresentado. Falta saber exatamente qual é o arquivo que ocorre isso. O PHP não gera nenhum tipo de log?

Comment: o resto do projeto ta normal, porque chamo um javascript.js e uso as funcoes que estao dentro ele, mas neste caso eu chamo uma funcao de outro javascript.js ai da erro do fire debug <code>SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' <br /> chama_d...bles.js (linha 1) ReferenceError: datatable is not defined paginac...atus.js (linha 18, col 21) ReferenceError: datatable is not defined paginac...atus.js (linha 34, col 21) ReferenceError: convertedate is not defined paginac...atus.js (linha 46, col 49) ReferenceError: convertedate is not defined paginac...atus.js (linha 61, col 49) <code>